# Render markdown in Rdlc report

Tags: c#, vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer

I am trying to render Markdown syntaxes in rdlc report viewer, but it displays raw as it is on the report. Is there a way I can render markdown on rdlc report viewer?

Comment: Can you please post some sample Markdown code?

Comment: Please see this link https://markdownlivepreview.com/  for samples of Markdown codes. Pasting them here will as well appear formated.

Comment: Understandable. I tested the sample markdown code, RDLC report does not support Markdown. You may need to compile the markdown to HTML format for RDLC before feeding as data.

Answer (score 1):

RDLC only support Markup language, you need to compile your Markdown code to HTML before feeding as data source.

You can edit your report template as following:

While editing your textbox, right click and choose **Create Placeholder...**

[image]

Then select Markup type be **HTML**

[image]